# How to refactor Linq Group By and Foreach statement into one Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

I am having some trouble trying to refactor the LINQ query below into one single query:

```
// produces 8 results
            var qryResults =
                (from r in dbContext.Routes
                 join br in dbContext.BrokerRoutes on r.RouteId equals br.RouteId
                 join pr in dbContext.RoutePathFilters.Include(x => x.PathFilter) on r.RouteId equals pr.RouteId into paths
                 where br.Broker.ApiKey == apiKey
                 select new RouteTemplate
                    {
                        RouteId = r.RouteId,
                        Version = r.Version.Version,
                        Url = r.Url,
                        IsActive = r.IsActive,
                        Paths = paths.Select(x => x.PathFilter.FilterName).ToList()
                 })
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToImmutableList();
```

```cs
// takes 8 results and turns that into 2 overall objects.
            var results = new List<RouteTemplate>();
            foreach (var r in qryResults)
            {
                if (results.All(x => x.RouteId != r.RouteId))
                {
                    r.Paths = qryResults
                        .Where(x => x.RouteId == r.RouteId)
                        .Select(x => x.Paths.First()).ToList();
                    results.Add(r);
                }
            }
```

`r` is duplicated by each value held in the `paths` property.

I know that foreach can be combined into the linq query above but i have been trying for a few hours now. So i am interesting know if it possible or not and how can it be done ?

Comment: What happens when you try to use the ForEach LINQ method on your ImmutableList directly?

Comment: @Stormhashe - this presents another option - ty - let me try it out.

Comment: cool, let me know if it worked. It's what I would think of doing, refactoring the code inside the foreach into a method, and using the ForEach LINQ method passing each elemente of the list to the inner method

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual database, I am not sure if this will work, but here is my attempt:

```
var qryResults =
    (from r in dbContext.Routes
     join br in dbContext.BrokerRoutes on r.RouteId equals br.RouteId
     where br.Broker.ApiKey == apiKey
     join pr in dbContext.RoutePathFilters.Include(x => x.PathFilter) on r.RouteId equals pr.RouteId into paths
     group new { r, paths } by r.RouteId into rprg
     let r = rprg.First().r
     select new RouteTemplate {
         RouteId = rprg.Key,
         Version = r.Version.Version,
         Url = r.Url,
         IsActive = r.IsActive,
         Paths = rprg.Select(rpr => rpr.paths.First().PathFilter.FilterName).ToList()
     })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToImmutableList();
```

Comment: I ran in this issue again and the simplest answer was to remove the projection statement and simply select from `rprg`.

Comment: Also: `rprg.First().r` will always assign the same values for each object in the collection. If the `version` or the `url` info is different, it will simply be overitten per result object projected out into the select statement.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz Your code only added the first `RouteId` for each set of `RouteId` to the `results`, the same as this LINQ.